# How to find limite of that multivariable function?

Tags: limits

$$\lim_{x\to1, y\to-1}{\frac{\arcsin{(x^5+y^5)}}{x^5+\tan{(x^4y+xy^4)}+\log{(1+x^3y^2+x^2y^3)}+y^5}}$$I have done the next:$$\arcsin(x^5+y^5)\sim{x^5+y^5}$$$$\tan{(x^4y+xy^4)}\sim{x^4y+xy^4}$$$$\log{(1+x^3y^2+x^2y^3)}\sim{x^3y^2+x^2y^3}$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\lim_{x\to1, y\to-1}{\frac{\arcsin{(x^5+y^5)}}{x^5+\tan{(x^4y+xy^4)}+\log{(1+x^3y^2+x^2y^3)}+y^5}} = \lim_{x \to 1, y \to -1} \frac{x^5+y^5}{x^5 + x^4y + xy^4 + x^3y^2+x^2y^3 + y^5} \\
= \lim_{x \to 1, y \to -1} \frac{(x+y)(x^4-x^3y+x^2y^2-xy^3+y^4)}{(x+y)(x^4-x^3y+x^2y^2-xy^3+y^4) +xy(x+y)(x^2-xy+y^2) + x^2y^2(x+y)}\\
= \frac{5}{3}$$

Answer (score 0):

You can factor the denominator:

$${x^5-y^5\over x^5+x^4y+x^3y^2+x^2y^3+xy^4+y^5} = {x^5-y^5\over (x+y)(x^2-xy+y^2)(x^2+xy+y^2)}$$

and rewrite it as

$$1 - {xy\over 2(x^2+xy+y^2)} - {xy\over2(x^2-xy+y^2)}$$

and then you can just insert $x=1, y=-1$ and get

$$1 - {-1\over 2(1-1+1)} - {-1\over2(1+1+1)} = {5\over 3}$$